# Writing custom c++14-style type aliases

Tags: c++, templates, alias, c++14

I wanted to create a `_t` alias for `std::is_base_of`, similar to how `std::enable_if_t` is an alias for `std::enable_if`. So I added the following to my standard header:

```
namespace std {
  template<typename T, typename U>
  using is_base_of_t = typename is_base_of<T,U>::type;
}
```

I'm using this new alias in the following context:

```
template <typename SpaceT,
          typename TagT,
          typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of_t<Space,SpaceT>>>
class SpatialTree : public SpaceT {
};
```

And I'm getting the following gcc error:

```
SpatialTree.h:48:101: error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for ‘template<bool _Cond, class _Tp> using enable_if_t = typename std::enable_if::type’
 template <typename SpaceT, typename TagT, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of_t<Space,SpaceT>>>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you should put this in another namespace, e.g. `xstd`, and upgrade to `std` when this becomes standardized

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`std::enable_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if) is defined thusly:

```
template< bool B, class T = void >
struct enable_if;
```

The first argument is a *value*, not a type. You need to pass in `std::is_base_of<Space,SpaceT>::value` as the first argument. With C++14, the correct alias would be a *variable* template:

```
template <class Base, class Derived>
constexpr bool is_base_of_v = std::is_base_of<Base, Derived>::value;
```

that you'd use the same way:

```
template <typename SpaceT, typename TagT,
          typename = std::enable_if_t<is_base_of_v<Space,SpaceT>>>
                                                ^^^
class SpatialTree : public SpaceT {
};
```

The latter currently exists in [`<experimental/type_traits>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/type_trait_variable_templates#is_base_of).

Answer (score 3):

[`enable_if`[`_t`]](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if) wants a `bool` as its first argument. You have to write `std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of_t<Space,SpaceT>::value>` or `std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of_t<Space,SpaceT>{}>`, otherwise you pass a type where a `bool` is required.

However, you might want to define a counterpart of [`std::experimental::is_base_of_v`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/type_trait_variable_templates#is_base_of) instead:

```
template <class Base, class Derived>
constexpr bool is_base_of_v = std::is_base_of<Base, Derived>{};
```

and use as `std::enable_if_t<is_base_of_v<Space, SpaceT>>`.

That said, I wouldn't define either of these templates in namespace `std`, since that invokes UB as per [namespace.std]/1.

Answer (score 2):

Available already as of Clang 3.6 and g++ 5.1

```
#include <experimental/type_traits>

using namespace std::experimental;

struct B {}; struct D : B {};

int main() 
{
    static_assert(is_base_of_v<B, D>, "");
}
```